# Outputting HTML code

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple code for work to help some coworkers out.  Basically I want them to be able to enter in 2 inputs and have a html code output.  For example:

input 1= corn

input 2 = delicious

```
output = <font color="#987654" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">corn</font>delicious
```

The current output is simply adding the html styling to the first input.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Cheers!

```
<head>
  <title></title>

  <style>
  #prod_name { height: 30px; width:700px; }
  #prod_desc { height: 30px; width:700px; padding-top:15px; }

  </style>

</head>

<body>

Title: <input id="prod_name"><br />
Description: <input id="prod_desc"><br />
<button id="convert">Convert to HTML</button>

<hr>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function convert_it() {
    var proname = document.getElementById('prod_name').value;
    var descname = document.getElementById('prod_desc').value;

    var html = '<font color="#987654" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">'  + proname + '</font> ' + descname;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = html;
}

document.getElementById('convert').addEventListener('click', convert_it);
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: works fine for me..http://jsfiddle.net/pox36L7e/

Comment: Don't use `<font>` it is outdated and obsolete, use span and apply css classes like you did for the inputs

Comment: @PatrickEvans - yes, definitely, but I still need it to output the raw html code and not the stylized inputs.

Comment: @TributetoAPJKalamSir - thanks for the response and sorry for not being clear, but I'm trying to have the output as the raw html code (i.e. <font color="#987654" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">corn</font>delicious ) & not the stylized inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/gratiafide/s6vq9tmo/

This literally outputs the HTML string:

```
<font color="#987654" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">corn</font> delicious
```

**Here's the JS:**

```
function convert_it() {
    var proname = document.getElementById('prod_name').value;
    var descname = document.getElementById('prod_desc').value;

    var html = '<font color="#987654" face="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">' + proname + '</font> ' + descname;

    document.getElementById('result').innerText = html;
}

document.getElementById('convert').addEventListener('click', convert_it);
```

Basically you need to use .innerText instead of .innerHTML